# Reference Text Cell in Excel Averageif

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to write an averageif formula in the line of averageif(A1:A5, "=* Text *", B1:B5)

But instead of "=* Text *" I want something like "= * A1 *"

Comment: `"=* "&A1&" *"`

Comment: That did not work for me. It makes sense though and I am not sure why. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: do you really want the spaces.  the string would literally need to be something like `this is my Text to find` and not `findTexthere`  If you do not want the spaces then remove the spaces in the quotes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The wording for the function description is very misleading, so you likely aren't referencing the correct cells.  The formula should be structured as so:

[image]